# Xcode reports errors, after building successfully

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5, xcode4.6

Xcode 4.5 (but also earlier I think) reports build errors, but I just created a successful build. And it also depends on which file I select in the project browser. Some files give errors, others don't.

This leads me to believe that there is a bug in the auto evaluation of my code. It seems to loose the #imports or deeper links to other headers...

I have been without the problem for a while, but today it returned. Very strange and annoying.

Is there an autocompletion cache to delete or something.
(Deleting derived data didn't help, or cleaning the build.)

Has anyone found a way to fix this?

edit: still happens in Xcode 4.6 
Might help to use @class more in headers, but unverified.

Comment: Okay, one solution I just thought of is to turn of 'live issues'. No real solution of course, but at least I won't be staring at false errors reports.

Comment: What are the errors generated?

Comment: Misc issues:
- "Expected a type" (for MBProgressHUD, which has been imported)
- "Use of undeclared identifier" for a class imported in the header.
It seems all definitions from custom source code included in the header are missing...

Comment: What do you mean by "custom source code"?  Are these non-system libraries that you have set the *Header Search Directories* for?

Comment: They are imports of my own source code. There are three imports. UIKit works, but my own two header files don't. The "Header Search Paths" is empty. "User Header Search Paths" points to my projects root folder. and ends in /**

Comment: Maybe deleting derived data helps after all. Under investigation